# select from 2 tables and search for a value

Tags: php, mysqli

I have two tables:

1. bookingbook
2. borrowbook

and I need to search the column `bookId` in each table if it's exist or not

**My code**

```
<?php
    while ($book = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
        $bokId = $book['id'];

        $checkBorrow = $db->prepare('SELECT
        a.bookId, b.bookId
        FROM
        bookingbook AS a
        INNER JOIN borrowbook AS b ON (a.bookId = b.bookId)
        WHERE a.bookId=? OR b.bookId=?
        ');
        $checkBorrow->bind_param('ii', $bokId, $bokId);
        $checkBorrow->execute();
        $res = $checkBorrow->get_result();
        $numRows = mysqli_num_rows($res);


        if ($numRows > 0) {
            $states = "Not Available";
        } elseif ($numRows <= 0) {
            $states = "Available";
        }
    }

?>
```

**Result** always comes `Available` even if it's not

```
bookingbook Table
id - insId - bookId - studentId
bookingbook Table
id - insId - bookId - studentId - borrowDate - restoreDate
```

Comment: *Caution:* You're mixing the procedural and object oriented style of `mysqli`.

Comment: @Rajdeep Paul can you please clear your Caution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you can do to get the number of rows returned,

```
while ($book = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    $bokId = $book['id'];

    // Prepare query
    $checkBorrow = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM bookingbook LEFT JOIN borrowbook ON 1=1 WHERE bookingbook.bookId=? OR borrowbook.bookId=? UNION SELECT * FROM bookingbook RIGHT JOIN borrowbook ON 1=1 WHERE bookingbook.bookId=? OR borrowbook.bookId=?');

    // Binds variables to prepared statement
    $checkBorrow->bind_param('iiii', $bokId, $bokId, $bokId, $bokId);

    // Execute query
    $checkBorrow->execute();

    // Store the result (to get properties)
    $checkBorrow->store_result();

    // Get the number of rows
    $numRows = $checkBorrow->num_rows;

    if ($numRows) {
        $states = "Not available";
    } else{
        $states = "Available";
    }

    // free results
    $checkBorrow->free_result();

    // close statement
    $checkBorrow->close();
}
```

*Caution:* You're mixing the procedural and object oriented style of `mysqli`. In the while loop condition you're using procedural style, whereas inside the while loop block you're using object oriented style of `mysqli`. Please pick one style and stick to it.

**Edited:**

*Updated SQL query*

```
// Prepare query
$checkBorrow = $db->prepare('
SELECT * FROM bookingbook LEFT JOIN borrowbook ON 1=1 WHERE bookingbook.bookId=? OR borrowbook.bookId=? 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM bookingbook RIGHT JOIN borrowbook ON 1=1 WHERE bookingbook.bookId=? OR borrowbook.bookId=?');

// Binds variables to prepared statement
$checkBorrow->bind_param('iiii', $bokId, $bokId, $bokId, $bokId);
```

Comment: the same result `Available`

Comment: @YousefAltaf If I'm right, you want to know if same `$bokId` exists in both the tables or not, right?

Comment: @YousefAltaf I've changed the conditions. check if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes you are right I need to check if the same `$bokId` exists in both the tables or not... but it seems that the edit is not working too now I get `Not Available` for the two of them :(

Comment: @YousefAltaf I've updated my answer. Please check now.

Comment: you just changed `Available` with `Not Available` and this also didn't work see I uploaded my file to `MS OneDrive` here you are the link you can see the all script  [MyScript](http://1drv.ms/1LLg7po)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96691/discussion-between-rajdeep-paul-and-yousef-altaf).

Comment: @YousefAltaf No, perhaps you missed, I also updated the SQL query and `bind_param`. Did you test it?